# How to improve the movement of an image within my ios App

Tags: ios, xcode, image

Within my ios App I need to move an image but I am encountering some problems. I am able to move the image correctly to the calculated coordinates, but I need to click on the button that initiates the movement twice before it will appear in the right position, os on the first click the image will only show at the initial position without relocating to the new position.

This is my code:

(EDITED)

Viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ndpViewController.h"

@interface ndpViewController ()

@end

@implementation ndpViewController
@synthesize image;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

}

-(void)dealloc
{
}

- (IBAction)calculatePush:(id)sender {
    image.hidden=NO;
    image.center=CGPointMake(376, 927);
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
}
@end
```

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ndpViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *calculate;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *image;
@end
```

Any idea why I need to click twice before the image will relocate?. I don't need any kind of animation, just a little image (representing a cross) that will show at a specific point on top of a graphic.

Thank you very much and regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted enough code to know for sure. But let me try it this way. What happens if zfw <= 26308 ?? It appears nothing. So in that case nothing moves. How does it EVER move when zfw is <= 26308?

NOTE:
Ok... the code as you have NOW posted it will NEVER relocate because you are always setting the position of the image to the same position on every click.

Comment: My apologies for that, I just tried to keep my post short to facilitate reading. I just edited my post above to show the code that covers all possible values of zfw.

Comment: All values are calculated from figures typed into text boxes, so the user fills in all text boxes and hits the button that will trigger the calculations and show the image in the correct place.As it is now: you type in the numbers,hit the button once and the calculations will be done correctly, but the img will not move from its initial position, you hit the button a second time and the image will move to the correct location. If you now modify any of the values in the text boxes and hit the button,the image will return to its initial position, and after a second click it will move again.

Comment: But the image shows correctly when zfw is <= than 26308. So I am not sure this is the problem I have, hiding and showing the image works fine, location fails. In any case I just updated the code above, and I still have the same problem, result is the same. :(

Comment: Now all conditionals are removed. Image declared like this> @property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *image; and the instruction to move it:  image.hidden=NO;
        image.center=CGPointMake(376, 927);

Comment: and I still have the same problem.. :(

Comment: Bottom line, still not enough code to know what is going on. How does zfw get its value. What sets that? Post it all or we can't help.

Comment: I simplified the code (please check above) so we can forget about zfw and any other calculation. I still have same result. Any specific part  of the code I could post to be more specific? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Same answer. There is NOTHING in the code you've posted which explains your problem.

Comment: All code I have is posted above. My apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly understand some of the code. But I think I understood your question which is 'How do I do something first click, and then something else on the second click?'

```
bool isFirstClick = true;

-(IBAction)CLickEvent:(id)sender{
    if(isFirstClick){
        //enter first click action here
        isFirstClick = false;
    }else{
        //enter second click action here
        isFirstClick = true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. THis is not really what I need to do. I just need to move an image to certain coordinates when I click on a button, from position A to position B. When you initiate the app, the image is hidden at position A. When I hit the button the first time, the image shows but stil at position A, and when I hit the button a second time it moves to position B. The correct action/result is what is happening on the second click, but I don't understand why this is not happening on just one click.

Comment: image.hidden=NO;
 image.center=CGPointMake(376, 927);

Comment: cant u just put image.hidden=NO; image.center=CGPointMake(376, 927) in one and image.hidden=YES; image.center=CGPointMake(different point, different point) in the other??

Comment: This is basically what I do, I just need to move it once from its initial position, but for some reason it doesn't move there until I do a second click. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is even more weird than I thought. The image moves at first click if I type text into any text box within the app, but it will only move at the second click if I type in numbers at the any of those text boxes.

Any suggestion????